# Vi Copy-paste without navigating to the line

Tags: vim, vi

Is it possible for me to say the copy the contents at a specific line (x) and paste in the current line without actually needing to go to x.

Right now, I need to type `:x<Enter>yy<C-o>p`. I just wanted to see if this can be done more efficiently.

Comment: The `:t` answer is the best, but if you wanted to stay out of command mode altogether you can also use `xG` to jump to line `x` (e.g. `7G`).

Answer (score 12):

there is `:t` you can use.

for example if you are on line #77, and you want to copy line#7 below your current line, that is, #78, you just:

```
:7t.
```

after executing this, your cursor will be on line#78, the newly "pasted" line.

read `:h :t` for details, you may want to know the powerful `:h range` as well.

another advantage of `:t` instead of `y/Y` is, you keep `"` register untouched.

Comment: Fun fact: `:7t.` actually moves you to line 7 then moves back to the curent line.

Answer (score 5):

The many ways to yank text in Vim

- `:copy` or `:t` command can copy a line. e.g. `:42t .`
- `:t` can take ranges w/ a search pattern. e.g. `:?foo?t.`
- Use `:yank` to yank a line. e.g. `:43y`
- Yank/copy multiple lines with `:global` command. e.g. `:g/foo/y A`
- Drop a mark and then search or go to link you want to yank then jump back to the mark. e.g. `` ma?foo<cr>yy`ap ``
- Use `<c-o>` similar to using marks to jump back.
- Use `g;` to move to older positions in the change list. (Similar to marks)

For more help see:

```
:h :t
:h range
:h :y
:h m
:h g;
:h ctrl-o
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command

```
:x,xy
```

That will yank line 'x' without moving your cursor and then you can just paste with p

**EDIT**

You can shorten the command to

```
:xy
```

That will grab line 'x'.  If you want a range of lines you could do this:

```
:x,x+10y
```

That will yank lines x - (x+10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getline()` function to read the line and the `append()` function to write it:

```
call append('.',getline('42'))
```

You can bundle it to a command if you want:

```
command! -nargs=1 FetchLine call append('.',getline(<q-args>))
FetchLine 42
```